# Filter out by each item in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have

```
<li ng-repeat="item in dummyData | unique:'status'" ng-click="select(item);" ng-class="{active: isActive(item)}"><a>{{item.status}}</a></li>
```

What I want to do is, on ng-click set

myFilter as

```
myFilter = {status: '{{item.status}}'}
```

What I want to do is I have

```
$scope.dummyData = [{id: 1, name="Joe", status="active"},{id: 2, name="Joe",status="inactive"},{id: 3, name="John", status="active"}];
```

Here I have li elements on ng-repeat and got unique status.

I have a table list with same dummy array which is filtered by myfilter.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in dummyData | filter:myfilter">
```

All i have to do is,

```
  <li ng-click='myfilter = {status: "active"}'><a>Active</a></li>
  <li ng-click='myfilter = {status: "inactive"}'><a>Inactive</a></li>
```

I have achieved this like this in static way, but I want to do it in repeat above.

Comment: i'm not sure to understand what you're trying to do, if you only want to filter the entries by their status, why note simple use filter:status

Comment: I'm new at this, ca you elaborate , i want to filter by item.status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the default filter uses partial matching you need to write a custom filter to do exact matching. Your updated controller will look like this:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.dummyData = [
        {id: 1, name:"Joe", status:"active"},
        {id: 2, name:"Jane",status:"inactive"},
        {id: 3, name:"John", status:"active"}];
    $scope.setFilter = function(statusValue) {
        $scope.myFilter = function(item) {
            return item.status === statusValue;
        };
    };
};
```

Note that the syntax for your dummyData was also incorrect so that would also cause a problem for you. Any time you click on Active or Inactive it will redefine the custom filter to match status exactly to 'active' or 'inactive'.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wk2MK/) that demonstrates what you want.

Comment: this does not work, i have added queries in my question. Please can you help.

Comment: I have to set myFilter = {status : item.status} on ng-click, so that corresponding table lists gets filtered

Comment: Okay, I see why the default filter doesn't work they way you want. I've updated my answer with a working example and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you should only use the default filter provided by angular, to do so your code will look like:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in dummyData | filter:status" ng-click="select(item);" ng-class="{active: isActive(item)}"><a>{{item.status}}</a></li>
```

Comment: No that is not what I want to do.I need to set myfilter by status in repeat in above so that list in a table below can be filtered.
  <tr ng-repeat="item in dummyData | filter:myfilter">

Comment: If MyFilter is a custom filter , you don't need to use "filter:myfilter" but " | myfilter:status "